# Does anybody know the complexity of finding a maximum clique in circulant graphs?

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-optimization, graphs, computational-complexity

I would be interested in knowing if finding a maximum clique in [circulant graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_graph) is NP-hard? Does anybody have any pointers or papers to suggest?

Answer (score 5):

It is NP-hard:

Bruno Codenotti, Ivan Gerace, Sebastiano Vigna.
Hardness results and spectral techniques for combinatorial problems on circulant graphs,
*Linear Algebra and its Applications* **285** (1-3), pages 123-142, 1998, [pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.78.6028&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Other Cayley graphs have been studied by Chris Godsil and Brendan Rooney in the paper [Hardness of Computing Clique Number and Chromatic Number For Cayley Graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00965), *European Journal of Combinatorics* **62**, pages 147-166, 2017